# Import FullCalendar in a mean angular4 application with PrimeNG Schedule

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, mean-stack, primeng

I am running an Angular4 mean application and I want to use [PrimeNG Schedule](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/schedule) to show events in a calendar. Schedule is build on [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/usage/), it in turn, needs jQuery and Moment.js to work. I used ap-ng2-fullcalendar version though because it is more compatible with Angular4.

So I installed jQuery, Moment, the FullCalendar and primeNG Scedule with npm.

I've put these imports in an app.module.ts

```
import {CalendarModule} from "ap-angular2-fullcalendar";
import {ScheduleModule} from 'primeng/components/schedule/schedule';
```

(and in imports:[...])

And have this in the html component (PrimeNG directive):

```
<p-schedule [events]="projects"></p-schedule>
```

But when I run the project I get an error:

```
ERROR ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

How do I get jQuery (and Moment) in my app? I can copy the jquery.js file from node_module/jquery/dist to my public folder and add it to html like so:

```
<script src="/js/plugins/jquery.js"></script>
```

But that is probably not the right way and then I get this when running the project:

```
TypeError: this.schedule.fullCalendar is not a function
```

I reckon that some js files are missing in my project and that jQuery and Moment need some manual importing of some sort but don't know how.
Note: I use webpack.

Thanks!

Comment: There are couple of ways on how to do this. You should take a look at [angular-cli-wiki on global scripts](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-scripts). That should give you some idea on how to do what you desire.

Comment: Are you using Angular CLI?

Comment: No I'm not using CLI, I use typescript with webpack. I think I got it now, it was a bug in moment https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/4228 and some misunderstanding on my side of how to import 3th party libraries that have no TypeScript (type) Definition. The ap-ng2-fullcalendar module actually neatly makes FullCalendar accessible in a setup like mine. Also useful to understand all this was https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qWSPog9Fz-o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use typescript with webpack. I think I got it now, it was a bug in moment https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/4228 and some misunderstanding on my side of how to import 3th party libraries that have no TypeScript (type) Definition. The ap-ng2-fullcalendar module actually neatly makes FullCalendar accessible in a setup like mine. Also useful to understand all this was https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qWSPog9Fz-o